# How to size from specific mount using ansible_mounts?

Tags: ansible

Looking for way to fetch "just" size_available of a particular mount point on remote host from ansible_hosts fact and set that as fact variable in playbook. Can't really figure that out - please share code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSON Query Filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) would do the job. For example *size_available* for *mount: /*

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_mounts|json_query('[?mount == `/`].size_available') }}"
```

gives:

```
"msg": [
    40047341568
]
```

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For Ansible 2.8.2 I found that the above solution didn't work and failed with:

```
templating error while templating string: expected token ',', got 'string'.
```

The following, however, worked (moving the query text to a variable):

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_mounts|json_query(jmesquery) | first }}"
  vars:
    jmesquery: "[?mount == `/`].size_available"
```

gives:

```
"msg": "40047341568"
```

Comment: make sure the controller machine has the jmesquery package: `pip install jmesquery`

Answer (score 0):

For a solution that does not depend on the `json_query` filter, which [requires the `jmespath` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/json_query_filter.html#requirements), you can use the built-in `selectattr` filter instead:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ (ansible_mounts | selectattr('mount', 'equalto', '/') | list)[0].size_available }}"
```